# Creating flowline by connecting points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, contour

I have a dataset that contains X,Y coordinates of a glacier and the surface elevation is plotted as a Z-coordinate (see attachment).

What I want to do is connect the top with the bottom of the glacier by a line, that goes perpendicular to the contours (a flowline). Does anyone know how this can be done? I thus want to create a transect (line) perpendicular to the contourlines...

[image]

Comment: Can't you just draw it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Any flow direction line will be perpendicular to the contours.  A simple but manual solution would be to create a Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN) from the points.  Use the TIN as the surface model in the 3D Analyst toolbar and use the Create Steepest Path tool to create your line.  A more involved solution would be to convert the points to a raster surface and use the hydrology tools in the spatial analyst toolbox to determine 'flow direction' for the surface of your glacier.